# Two Font Awesome versions on the same page

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

Is there a good solution for having 2 different Font Awesome versions on the same web page?

The case is that we have a CMS page editing tool which gets inlined in the web page/context
We want to use Font Awesome for the editing tool UI, but since it is inlined together with the user's page there is a possibility that their page embeds a Font Awesome version too and conflicts may arise.

So I am looking for an idea for how to scope the Font Awesome used by the CMS editing tool .. or any other good solution.

Comment: to clear things up: you need to close the whole FA stylesheet in a different scope?